# How to check which partial is currently active in mvc3?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I check which partial is currently active(which one is currently in the DOM), so i can apply Css, also how can I set some kind of anchor, so user can copy-paste URL for specific partial?

EDIT:

Lets say I have three links, first link returns _Partial1, second _Partial2... ActionLinks have  `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` so they replace same element... Active one is the one currently used by the user...

Comment: What do you mean by 'active'?

Comment: @rich.okelly, by active I mean which one is on the page, lets say three tabs, for three partial, with replace method

Comment: I don't know what you mean by which partial is currently active. But you cannot copy/paste a URL for a Partial view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know the partial when you render it, I'd suggest having a div container with appropriate id eg:

```
<div id="Partial1">
  ...
</div>
```

You can then style the content inside it thusly:

```
#Partial1 div { //style here }
#Partial1 .myClass { //style here }
```

And link to it like so:

```
<a href="http://www.yourDomain.com/somePage#Partial1">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First part of your question is answered by @rich.okelly, the other one about the link - well, You can pass GET parameter (?selectedPartial=partialName) to your page's URL, than you will need to add a logic in your controller/action to check if that one is set, and if so, set the partial it points to as the one to load on page render.

Update :

you can add GET param like that :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", "Controller", new { partial = "selectedParialNameHere" }, null)
```

when on your controller you would need :

```
string PartialToLoad =  Request["partial"].toString();
```

Comment: you have an example of passing GET param to URL?